# How to read in multiple types from an input?

Tags: c

My input file looks like this.

```
 00 READ 9
 01 READ 10
 02 WRIT 9
 03 LOAD 10
```

I can only use 5 integer variables ( like - reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5 ) and have to read in each line and convert the instructions, like READ, into its corresponding code, 10.

The information read in will be stored in an integer array of length 100. So the first few lines would be read and converted and stored like so:

```
 0     1    2
 1009  1010 1109
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: What are the corresponding codes for the other instructions and what are the other instructions? How are we to guess what code corresponds to each instruction (like what number corresponds ot 'LOAD')? Also what do you mean by '5 integers'? Are there five instructions or?

Comment: We are constructing a very "basic" assembly compiler. So to list all of the instructions and their corresponding opcodes would be a waste of space. I am having a hard time coming up with a method or algorithm that could read in the integer, read in the string and convert it to its opcode, read in the last integer and continue until it reaches the end of file. All while only using 5 integer variables.

Comment: How are you going to convert READ to its code if you're not allowed to use a string or something to hold it? Just asking how the assignment has been given. As far as I can tell your file doesn't give the code for the instruction, only the line number and the value to be read.

Comment: We are supposed to figure out how to read it in and convert it to the proper code.

Comment: Does it matter what READ is converted to? I mean can you assign any code to it as long as it is unique or it has to be a specific code (like 10)?

Comment: This is what I have for codes for instructions.                     enum opCode { READ = 10, WRIT, PRNT, LOAD = 20, STOR, ADD = 30, SUB, DIV, MULT, MOD, BRAN = 40, BRNG, BRZR, HALT = 99 };

Comment: I honestly cannot think of a way at the moment of parsing `READ` from the file and not storing it somewhere temporary but I'll try to get back to you with an idea.

Comment: Btw, how are you going to read the file if you don't have a buffer to store it as you're reading it? Can you make an exception for that?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, every mnemonic is 4 bytes straight. You can simply allocate a 32-bit integer and feed its address to a data reading routine for reading 4 bytes. Then "READ" would turn 1145128274, "WRIT" - 1414091351, and so on. That's much easier to compare than strings.

Or the other way around - read all input and then set the (int*) pointer to the mnemonic. Something like that:

```
char input[]="10 READ 09";
int* opcode = (int*)&input[3];
if( *opcode == 1145128274 ) // then it's READ
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the most efficient way of going about this but after reading in the first integer as the address I called a function that performs the following code to convert the instructions to their corresponding integer values.

I have used an enumeration to set the instructions to their corresponding values in the beginning of the code.

```
getchar();
*reg1 = (int)getchar();
*reg2 = (int)getchar();
*reg3 = (int)getchar();
*reg4 = (int)getchar();

switch( *reg1 ){
    case (int)'R':
        if( *reg2 == (int)'E' && *reg3 == (int)'E' && *reg4 == (int)'D' ){
            *reg4 = READ;
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    case (int)'W':
        ...
```

}